# Java: How to enter multiple values on the same line?

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
 package assignment.pkg1;

 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Exercise3 {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter three integers: ");

    byte t1 = scan.nextByte() , t2 = scan.nextByte(), t3 = scan.nextByte(); }

/* I'm getting this result for example: 
Enter three integers: 10
20
30

I want to get this result: 10 20 30 */
```

How can i get the three inputs on the same line?

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expressions, Pattern, and Matcher

```
String input = user_input.nextLine();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)|([a-zA-Z]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
List<String> nums = new LinkedList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    String num = m.group(1);   
    nums.add(num);
    System.out.println(nums);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the input as a string. Use Regx and separate the string and get it into an array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int length = 3;

    System.out.print("Enter three integers: ");
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    String[] array = s.split("\\s", -1);
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length;i++){
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the entire line as a String. 
Then split the line on spaces into an array of Strings. 
Then parse the strings into bytes.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter three integers: ");
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
byte t1 = Byte.valueOf(numbers[0]);
byte t2 = Byte.valueOf(numbers[1]);
byte t3 = Byte.valueOf(numbers[2]);
```

Keep in mind that you shouldn't press return until after you have entered the 3rd number.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely enter all three numbers in one line, the way you want.